# Cordova PHP get back to the original page

Tags: javascript, php, android, cordova

I am building a Cordova ( intel XDk app ) with HTML CSS and JavaScript.
For Backend i use PHP. I want that after the php finishes it's job, it will return to a specific page in my app, let's say #menupage.
This is my php code:

```
    <?php
echo 'welcome ';
echo $_GET["name"];
echo 'your password is ';
echo  $_GET["password"];
echo '<button onclick="activate_page("#menupage");">Go to the menu</button>';
 ?>
```

I want the button to activate that function, but it doesn't. Every other Javascript code I try doesn't work. Can somebody help me please.

Answer (score 0):

you have a wrong sequnce of quotes  try assign properly and escape the inner quotes

```
 echo '<button onclick="activate_page(\'#menupage\');">Go to the menu</button>';
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, but my problem is that the button and the text are still in an external Page opened in Chrome. How can I make them be opened inside the Cordova in-app browser, I mean I want the content to be in my app, not in an external Page. Is that possible?