# external PHP echo in a local HTML file

Tags: php, html, cordova

I have an external PHP, located on a hosting server. The app that I want to build is using Cordova, so I have a HTML on my phone local storage. I have a login form that POSTS to that external php the name and the password of the user. I want that when I click on submit, to stay on my current page, and display the values recieved by the PHP below the form, in a `<p>` or `<h1>` tag.

I will be grateful if you can help me with this.

Comment: you can either post to self or use ajax. You also did not include any code.

Comment: this seems a repost of http://stackoverflow.com/q/43028235/1415724 where you were given an answer for it and posting a comment relevant to the posted question here [*"How can I make them be opened inside the Cordova in-app browser, I mean I want the content to be in my app, not in an external Page"*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43028235/cordova-php-get-back-to-the-original-page#comment73142689_43028283)

Comment: You need to delete this question since it's a repost and update your previous question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cordova PHP get back to the original page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43028235/cordova-php-get-back-to-the-original-page)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Ajax to get the content/data to your view from an external file.

You will need [jQuery](https://jquery.com/download/) to use `$.ajax()`.

```
//Get form Data
var form_data = $('#form').serialize();

$.ajax({
  url:'http://something.com/dosomthing.php',
  type:'POST',
  data: form_data,
  success:function(data){
    // See what data was returned
    console.log(data); 
    if(data.success == "1"){
      $('#err-element').html("User Authenticated");
      // Fade in new Page
    }else{
      $('#err-element').html("User Not found");
    }
  }
});
```

It is good practice to return a JSON object from your back-end.

```
if($user_matches){
  echo json_encode(["success"=>"1", "OtherInfo"=>"Kitty"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

post the data to the same page using query or something, use post or get variable  to store it in a variable and append with javascript.

```
   //post using query
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data:{ whatyouwant: yourdata }
   }) 

    //in php 
   $data = $_GET['whatyouwant']; 

   //in javascript 

   data = '<?php echo $data;?>';   // if it's a string or you can use json_encode for arrays and such

    $('#targetDiv').html('<p>'+data+'</p>');
```